# Import Error in Rust with the crate "amcl"

Tags: rust, cryptography

I am following a tutorial and the rust code uses the line

```
use amcl::secp256k1::{ecdh, ecp};
```

I get the error (*could not find secp256k1 in amcl*)

The Crate **amcl** doesn't seem to have this method

https://docs.rs/amcl/0.2.0/amcl/

Can someone confirm that the tutorial is wrong, and it's not me doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It [appears to be there](https://docs.rs/amcl/0.2.0/src/amcl/lib.rs.html#402-417) behind a feature gate. Add the `"secp256k1"` feature to the `amcl` dependency in your `Cargo.toml`.

Comment: I think you are right, and I am implement what you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

There no module `secp256k1` in [`amcl`](https://docs.rs/amcl/0.2.0/amcl/)

`secp256k1` is named as `NIST256` in [`amcl`](https://docs.rs/amcl/0.2.0/amcl/) you can read more about it [`here`](https://github.com/miracl/amcl/issues/2)